# What can be causing the error shown in the attached picture?

Tags: dart

The getter 'documents' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.
Try importing the library that defines 'documents', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'documents'
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BC7Ww.jpg)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

that's because it cannot know the type of `snapshot.data`, so you need to cast it to your wanted class. you have to options,

first, use
`var userDocument = snapshot.data as UserDocument;`
or second, if that's a `FutureBuilder`, you can define it's type like this: `FutureBuilder<UserDocument>`